# PHP + Laravel + Vue - Unexpected token '<' at app.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js

I have a PHP+Vue project that I inherited from another programmer. I know the code should work because it's currently hosted on a server and running.

I downloaded the files to make some changes, and tried to run it locally (using Wampserver). However, when I try to access the site I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at app.js:1:1).

What I tried:
Looking into app.js (and app.css for that matter) in DevTools shows an HTML file (seems to be from base.blade.php) instead of javascript code. I checked every app.js file I could find on the project's folder and found actual code.
It seems like the wrong file is being served, but I don't know why or how to fix it. I don't have any experience with PHP.

Code:

app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
const files = require.context('./components', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

bootstrap.js:

```
window._ = require('lodash');
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

base.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link href="{{ env('APP_ENV') == 'development' ? mix('css/app.css') : asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" defer>
    <script src="{{ env('APP_ENV') == 'development' ? mix('js/app.js') : asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    {{-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> --}}
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    @stack('head')
    @stack('style')
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @yield('main')
    </div>
</body>
@stack('script')
</html>
```

Comment: so , have you figured out what the html you are receiving is trying to tell you ?  looked at the web-server logs ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Hi. The html I get seems to be generated from base.blade.php and other files that extend it in the Layouts folder. It's not a response from an API or anything like that.

Comment: Please show some code (app.js and base.blade.php will be a great start).

Comment: @GonrasKarols Hi! I edited the original post with some code.

Comment: @CNacho The html is probably a stack trace, but whou can know ??? ... just a wag The information you should put in your question. Without the specific error, nobody can help you.